# Tidy up if and elseif statement

Tags: php, html

I've hacked together this code with various if and elseif statement's and just wondering if it could be tidied up (my syntax knowledge is rubbish!):

Rather than show ALL the html code again (because it's the same) is there a way I can combine all the elseif and if's into one?

```
if(in_array("Branding", get_field('categories')) && $grid_title == "Branding"){
     echo "
        <div class=\"grid-box\" onclick=\"location.href='" . get_page_link($post->ID) ."';\" style=\"cursor: pointer;\">
        <div class=\"phase-1\">
           <img class=\"grid-image\" src=\"" . $fields->thumb_image . "\" alt=\"" . $fields->company_name ."\" height=\"152\" width=\"210\" />
           <div class=\"grid-heading\">
                <h2>". $fields->company_name ."</h2>
                <h3>" . implode(', ',get_field('categories')) ."</h3>
            </div> 
        </div>
        <div class=\"phase-2\">
            <div class=\"grid-info\">
                <h4>". $fields->project_name ."</h4>
                <p>". $fields->description ."</p>
            </div>
            <div class=\"grid-heading-hover\">
                <h2>". $fields->company_name ."</h2>
                <h3>". implode(', ',get_field('categories')) ."</h3>
            </div> 
        </div>
    </div>
     ";
}
elseif(in_array("Web", get_field('categories')) && $grid_title == "Web"){
     echo "
        <div class=\"grid-box\" onclick=\"location.href='" . get_page_link($post->ID) ."';\" style=\"cursor: pointer;\">
        <div class=\"phase-1\">
           <img class=\"grid-image\" src=\"" . $fields->thumb_image . "\" alt=\"" . $fields->company_name ."\" height=\"152\" width=\"210\" />
           <div class=\"grid-heading\">
                <h2>". $fields->company_name ."</h2>
                <h3>" . implode(', ',get_field('categories')) ."</h3>
            </div> 
        </div>
        <div class=\"phase-2\">
            <div class=\"grid-info\">
                <h4>". $fields->project_name ."</h4>
                <p>". $fields->description ."</p>
            </div>
            <div class=\"grid-heading-hover\">
                <h2>". $fields->company_name ."</h2>
                <h3>". implode(', ',get_field('categories')) ."</h3>
            </div> 
        </div>
    </div>
     ";

}
else {
    echo "hello";
}
```

Comment: This should be on Code Review.

Comment: whats the different (incontent) between two first options?

Comment: The content is the same for both but the if's are slightly different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The elseif does the same as the first if. So move the condition to the first one with OR and remove elseif:

```
if((in_array("Branding", get_field('categories')) && $grid_title == "Branding") || (in_array("Web", get_field('categories')) && $grid_title == "Web")){
     echo "
        <div class=\"grid-box\" onclick=\"location.href='" . get_page_link($post->ID) ."';\" style=\"cursor: pointer;\">
        <div class=\"phase-1\">
           <img class=\"grid-image\" src=\"" . $fields->thumb_image . "\" alt=\"" . $fields->company_name ."\" height=\"152\" width=\"210\" />
           <div class=\"grid-heading\">
                <h2>". $fields->company_name ."</h2>
                <h3>" . implode(', ',get_field('categories')) ."</h3>
            </div> 
        </div>
        <div class=\"phase-2\">
            <div class=\"grid-info\">
                <h4>". $fields->project_name ."</h4>
                <p>". $fields->description ."</p>
            </div>
            <div class=\"grid-heading-hover\">
                <h2>". $fields->company_name ."</h2>
                <h3>". implode(', ',get_field('categories')) ."</h3>
            </div> 
        </div>
    </div>
     ";
}
else {
    echo "hello";
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You should consider using PHP's [Heredoc](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc) to delimit strings. That would help get rid of the echo and all the escape `\' characters.

Use PHP's [if/else/elseif/endif](http://designerfoo.com/php-shorthand-php-alternative-alternate-syntax-a-quickie.html) short-hand syntax. It makes it read easier:

```
if(condition) :
  //statments
elseif(condition) :
  //statments   
endif;
```

Comment: What's wrong with using the short-hand syntax? I personally find it easier to read

Answer (score 1):

If I was you, I'd keep the HTML as plain text, not a PHP string :

```
<?php if(condition) : ?>
  // html
<?php elseif(condition) : ?>
  // html
<?php endif; ?>
```

It makes it way easier to read IMO.